How to use stacked bars graphs with 2 different types bars
I have created bar charts for different types of Income (A and B), which in turn these amounts are divided into two categories C and D. All this data is grouped by Month, what I need to achieve is that I want to show the two Bars (A, B) by Month and also show C and D in each parent bar (A and B) stacked and the value of C and D within A and B is shown. Can this be done? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.
enter image description here
I have read the documentation and checked all the examples but I did not succeed.

Please create a Sencha Fiddle with mock data to demonstrate your issue and I will be happy to have a look at it. Please respond with @ so that I get a notification.
